# Live stream output from JS MediaRecorder to Python speech recognition server via soket.io

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to stream microphone from my browser to a server running a Python service connected to the google cloud speech-to-text. For the transfer I'm using socket.io. Everything seems to work but the speech recognition doesn't return any result. I suspect a problem with the format of the sent data.
On my browser I'm using the *MediaRecorder* with the mime type *audio/webm;codecs=opus*.

```js
// simpleTest.js
'strict';

// Configuration
var language = 'fr-FR';
var mimeType = 'audio/webm;codecs=opus';    // Valid sample rates: 8000, 12000, 16000, 24000, 48000
var format = 'WEBM_OPUS';   // Valid sample rates: 8000, 12000, 16000, 24000, 48000
var sampleRate = 16000;

var recording = false;
var audioStream = null;
var mediaRecorder = null;
var audioChunks = [];

var namespace = '/ingestor'; // change to an empty string to use the global namespace

// Initialize socket
var socket = io(namespace);
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("connected to the SocketServer " + namespace);
});

socket.on('my_response', function (msg, callback) {
    console.log("received message from the SocketServer " + namespace);
    $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('logs #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
    if (callback)
        callback();
});

socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.error("Socket connection error: " + error);
});

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log("Socket disconnected: " + reason);
    if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
        // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
        socket.connect();
    }
});

const sendMessage = async (aSocket, msg) => {
    if (aSocket.connected) {
        aSocket.emit('my_event', {data: msg});
    }
}

const initRecording = () => {
    recording = false;
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
        navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    }

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {

            // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
            const getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

            // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
            // to keep a consistent interface
            if (!getUserMedia) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
            }

            // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
            });
        }
    }

    // Initialize audio stream
    console.log("Creating audio stream");
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
    .then((stream) => {
        console.log("Audio stream successfully created");
        audioStream = stream;
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
            audioBitsPerSecond: sampleRate,
            mimeType: mimeType
        });
        console.log('mimeType: ' + mediaRecorder.mimeType);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error while creating the audio stream");
        console.log(error);
    });
};


const startRecording = () => {
    recording = true;
    console.log('startRecording');
    mediaRecorder.start(1000);
};


const stopRecording = () => {
    recording = false;
    console.log('stopRecording');
    mediaRecorder.stop();
};


const handleDataAvailable = (event) => {
    console.log('handleDataAvailable');
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        console.log(event.data);
        handleBlob(event.data);
    }
};

const handleBlob = (blob) => {
    console.log('handleBlob - blob type: ' + blob.type);
    blob.arrayBuffer()
        .then((buffer) => {
            console.log(buffer);
            console.log(audioChunks.length + '. ' + buffer);
            sendMessage(socket, JSON.stringify({
                type: 'audio',
                content: {
                    command: 'stream',
                    audioData:  new Uint8Array(buffer)
                }
            }));
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

window.toggleRecording = () => {
    if (!recording) {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

initRecording();
```

On the server side I specify in the *google.cloud.speech.RecognitionConfig* the encoding is *google.cloud.speech.AudioEncoding.WEBM_OPUS*. This way I suppose I'm using the same container and codec. Right?
The server is divided in two parts:

- the ingestor reading the socket and writing the data as received to a redis queue
- the transcriber reading the redis queue and transferring the data to the Google cloud text-to-speech

```py
# Ingestor
import queue
import time
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, copy_current_request_context
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
import redis

eventlet.monkey_patch()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
redisHost = 's2t_memory_store'
redisPort = 6379
redisQueue = 'livequeue'
id = 'ingestor'
maxPackets = 500

async_mode = None
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')

thread = None

redisDatabase = redis.Redis(host=redisHost, port=redisPort, db=0,
                            health_check_interval=2, socket_timeout=3)
buffer = queue.Queue()

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/ingestor')
def connect():
    print('%s socket connected!' % id)
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(_enqueue_audio, redisQueue)

@socketio.on('my_event', namespace='/ingestor')
def handle_data(data):
    """Stores the received audio data in a local buffer."""
    buffer.put(data['data'], block=False)
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': data['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']})

def _enqueue_audio(redis_queue):
    """Blocking-reads data from the buffer and adds to Redis queue."""
    print('%s enqueue_audio thread started!' % id)
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = buffer.get(block=True)
            print('Buffer read: {}'.format(chunk))
            val = redisDatabase.lpush(redis_queue, chunk)
            # debugging; under normal circumstances audio should not be accumulating
            if val > 5:
                print('Ingested audio queue length: %d' % val)
        except redis.exceptions.RedisError as err:
            print('Error pushing into Redis queue: %s' % err)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html', sync_mode=socketio.async_mode)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting ingestor")
    socketio.init_app(app)
```

```py
# Transcriber
import redis
import json
from google.cloud import speech


encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.WEBM_OPUS
sample_rate = 16000
language_code = 'fr-FR'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
redis_host = 's2t_memory_store'
redis_port = 6379
redis_queue = 'livequeue'
id = 'transcriber'


class redisStream(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port, queue):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.queue = queue
        self.redis_conn = redis.Redis(host=self.host, port=self.port)

def redis_generator(redis_conn, redis_queue):
    while True:
        yield redis_conn.blpop(redis_queue)[1]

def main():
    redis_conn = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, db=0,
                             health_check_interval=2,
                             socket_timeout=None,
                             socket_connect_timeout=None)

    speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()
    recognition_config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=encoding,
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate,
        language_code=language_code)
    streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        config=recognition_config,
        interim_results=True)

    for message in redis_generator(redis_conn, redis_queue):
        print(f'REDIS STREAM: {message}')
        messageData = json.loads(message)
        if messageData['content']['command'] == 'stream':
            print('AUDIO DATA: %s' % messageData['content']['audioData'])
            chunk = bytes(messageData['content']['audioData'].values())
            print('CHUNK: %s' % chunk)
            request = speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
            responses = speech_client.streaming_recognize(config=streaming_config, requests=[request])
            print('RESPONSES: %s' % responses)
            if responses:
                for response in responses:
                    for i, result in response.results:
                        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
                        print("-" * 20)
                        print(u"First alternative of result {}".format(i))
                        print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
                        print(u"Confidence: {}".format(alternative.confidence))
                        print("-" * 20)
            else:
                print('No response')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting transcriber")
    main()
```

What is wrong? Do you have somewhere an example of the best (right) way to realize the transfer of such a live stream?

I have read many threads and publications on the web but I was never able to make it run correctly.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: pls write some code you tried to solve your problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my question by adding some pieces of my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some Python code or show your code that did not fix the issue you were seeing.